# Duplicating __m256i datatype

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I'm interested in copying the data of a __m256i datatype (used in Intel Intrinsics for AVX instructions) to a new __m256i.

I'm aware that I can store the data from the AVX register to memory and then from memory, I can load the data into a new register. However, is there a more simple way (i.e. a dedicated instruction for it), where I can directly "clone" the register without first using operations for storing it to memory and then loading it again?

I guess, I could add an empty register to my register, and then get a new __m256i type back that can be loaded into a register... This seems as a bit of a hack, however, and requires I use some operations to create a new empty __m256i dummy at some point.

Sorry if it is a simple question (it is a simple problem). I just haven't been able to find a single intrinsic function that could do this for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do assignment in the usual way, e.g.

```
__m256i v1 = _mm256_set1_epi32(42);
__m256i v2 = v1;
```

The compiler will typically generate a `vmovdqa` instruction (or it may even just optimise away the register copy).

Comment: Ahh, how fantastic. Hard to find that useful info on the Intel Intrinsics landing page, but that makes it really easy! I had thought that would have been handled as references, so they were pointing to the same data-element then!

Comment: Yes, it probably seems blindingly obvious now, but you can just treat a `__m256i` like any other simple type, e.g. `int`, as far as many fundamental operations are concerned. Just as an `int` may get allocated by the compiler to a general purpose scalar register, an `__m256i` may get allocated to a `ymm` register.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily copy a YMM register in x86 assembly to another one using [MOVDQA](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA.html)

```
vmovdqa ymm0, ymm1
```

The corresponding intrinsic of this is

```
_mm256_store_si256(_m256i *p, __m256i a);
```

The compiler should optimize away any variable references.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had completely misunderstood Intel's documentation. This helps!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend writing a `store` intrinsic for copying data between local variables, where you don't expect an actual store to memory.  The `store` / `storeu` intrinsics mainly exist to communicate alignment guarantees to the compiler, otherwise you'd just write `*p = a;`